# Does backend systems like IIB, WSRR, Data Power etc support Restful web services?

Tags: ibm-datapower, ibm-odm, ibm-integration-bus, wsrr

Does backend systems (WSRR, DP, ODM, MDM, IIB, etc) support Restful web services? I know they support Soap!

Also, if my application is developed using IIB, WSRR, Data Power etc with SOAP web services, can they be converted to Restful web services? Is that a possibility?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to read [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0903_peterson/0903_peterson.html) ? - or tried google for the other parts of your question?

Comment: Of course I did! But not much luck. Very little information is available on IIB V10

Comment: Datapower able to make all the things with HTTP you can imagine. Since REST is based on HTTP - yes at least DP supports it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they support RESTful web services.

For the second part of your question, SOAP services can be converted to REST in them; for some it's easy (e.g. ODM) and for some, it requires some work (e.g. IIB).

Comment: Okay. And is there any article that discusses how to convert the SOAP services to REST in IIB? I tried to find something but not much luck.

Comment: I don't think you can find one. In summary, you should reimplement your flow, but start it with an HTTPInput node and end it with an HTTPReply node, instead of SOAPInput/SOAPReply nodes. It also changes your data format from SOAP to JSON, so you have to modify your transformation logic accordingly.